# How does actual "signing" happen "offline" via API?

Tags: docusignapi

We currently use the API for embedded signing in our web application.  When reviewing [doc reference guide for offline signing](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Offline%20Signing.htm?Highlight=offline), I'd say it's less than crystal clear how that really works. If I'm offline when I obviously can't call the API, so how does one in fact "sign" with DS?

I can appreciate how our client app (again, which currently does embedded signing) can prepare an envelope 'request' offline, and then send that request once we have connectivity.  However the REST API guide says the user in fact "signs" the doc while offline -- how does the user ever get to the Docusign interface to do signing?

from the docs

> To use Offline Signing, the customer using a client application to
>   create an envelope on an Internet-capable device, such as a smart
>   phone or tablet, that is not connected to the Internet and has a
>   recipient fill out and sign (or initial) the envelope documents. When
>   the device later connects to the Internet, the client application
>   uploads the envelope information to DocuSign where it is processed.

Does our offline app (running, say, in/as a Chrome app) somehow connect to local client Docusign software onboard the laptop or mobile device while offline?  Any pointers to more complete documentation?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> "IMPORTANT: Access to the offline signing capability is limited by
>   integrator key information. If your integrator key does not have the
>   correct authorization, you cannot use offline signing. Access to the
>   offline signing capability will be evaluated on a case-by-case basis."

The reason is because your software would be responsible for providing the legal evidence that the transaction actually happened with the proper security checks.  This requires a tighter business arrangement and agreement between your company and DocuSign.

Please get in touch with your business development manager and they can set up a time to talk.

-mb

Comment: Hope this doesn't sound defensive or snarky, but I DID read the docs, and I understand I need special dispensation from DS.  I'd still like to understand the basics of the offline workflow and this didn't answer it.  I want to understand if there's anything that DS software actually does in an offline scenario... or is it 100% custom up to us to display a populated PDF, capture signature 'somehow', and only thing that DS does when back online is allow us to call API with a full document (in byte code) and the first signer identified as complete?

Comment: Hey!  No problem at all.  The instructions on how to use offline signing or how it works won't be on StackOverflow until the protocol is deemed suitable to be public.  Hope that makes sense.